# Duplicate last row of every group in a data.table and change the value of one column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a `data.table` like the following:

```
    ID Date        v3  v4
     1 2015.01.01   a   5
     1 2015.02.01   b   5
     1 2015.03.01   f   1
     1 2015.04.01   z   5
     1 2015.05.01   a   2
     2 2013.03.01   a   6
     2 2013.04.01   a   2
     2 2013.05.01   g  13
     2 2013.06.01   a   2
     2 2013.07.01   e   8
     2 2013.08.01   h   9
     2 2013.09.01   h   9
```

And I would like to insert a row at the end of every group (by ID), which would be the same as the last row except for the date, which should be one month more, than the last observation:

```
    ID Date        v3  v4
     1 2015.01.01   a   5
     1 2015.02.01   b   5
     1 2015.03.01   f   1
     1 2015.04.01   z   5
     1 2015.05.01   a   2
     1 2015.06.01   a   2
     2 2013.03.01   a   6
     2 2013.04.01   a   2
     2 2013.05.01   g  13
     2 2013.06.01   a   2
     2 2013.07.01   e   8
     2 2013.08.01   h   9
     2 2013.09.01   h   9
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please `dput` your data example. This is especially important when asking questions involving dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the last row and rbind with the dataset

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
rbind(setDT(df1), df1[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%Y.%m.%d")][,
       .SD[.N], ID][, Date := Date %m+% months(1)])[order(ID)]
#    ID       Date v3 v4
# 1:  1 2015-01-01  a  5
# 2:  1 2015-02-01  b  5
# 3:  1 2015-03-01  f  1
# 4:  1 2015-04-01  z  5
# 5:  1 2015-05-01  a  2
# 6:  1 2015-06-01  a  2
# 7:  2 2013-03-01  a  6
# 8:  2 2013-04-01  a  2
# 9:  2 2013-05-01  g 13
#10:  2 2013-06-01  a  2
#11:  2 2013-07-01  e  8
#12:  2 2013-08-01  h  9
#13:  2 2013-09-01  h  9
#14:  2 2013-10-01  h  9
```

Note: It may be better to convert the 'Date' to `Date` class

Or as @Frank mentioned, `seq.Date` from `base R` can be used to get the sequence of 'month'

```
rbind(setDT(df1), df1[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%Y.%m.%d")][,
     .SD[.N], ID][, Date := seq(Date, length.out = 2, by = 'month')[2], by = ID])[order(ID)]
```

Comment: Don't need an extra package, I guess, maybe `seq(d, length.out=2, by="month")` or something. (I didn't read the OP closely.)